# Adding a CV document to an Article document in Overleaf

Tags: cv, multiple-files, documentclass

I'm writing an article in Overleaf using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

I have several sections in this document.

I'd like to add a CV under one of these sections.

Any idea how I could do this?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you know `pdfpage`?

Comment: Thanks - I've tried and it's so far the best option. But I'd really like the text to start under the title of the section and not another page

Answer (score 0):

If You have Your CV in .pdf like CV.pdf (if not You should convert) You can easy add it as image: \includegraphics{cv.pdf}

Comment: thanks a lot - I've tried but the quality isn't great

Comment: If You really tried to put it .pdf format the quality MUST BE great or You already have pixeled picture of CV

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't great. also, I'd like to be able to edit the entire document easily

Comment: Ok, so, if You want to edit it You should   read about how to put another .tex file into your main.tex file (it is enough easy)